# GameObject.Find not working with string var

Tags: unity-game-engine, find, coroutine, gameobject

I cannot get GameObject.Find to work by passing a string variable as an agrument.

Here is the code:

```
public IEnumerator GetControls(string uri)
{
    using (UnityWebRequest webRequest = UnityWebRequest.Get(uri))
    {
        yield return webRequest.SendWebRequest();
        controls = new JSONObject(webRequest.downloadHandler.text);
        GameObject controlGO;
        string keyName;
        foreach (JSONObject control in controls)
        {
            keyName = control["keyName"].ToString();
            controlGO = GameObject.Find(keyName);          //WONT FIND IT
            controlGO = GameObject.Find("growLight3");     //WILL FIND IT
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you try a Debug.Log(keyName) to see what it returns? It may be getting the wrong name.

Comment: Yes I did it is the proper name.. :/ it just wont get it